# Boostrap carrusel in rails not working for mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap carousel on Rails that works correctly. The problem is that on mobile devices, it doesn't start automatically. However, if I manually start moving the carousel items, it begins to move automatically. Additionally, once it has started working, if I reload the page, it continues to work.Can someone help me with this?

this is the code:

```
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="3000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <%= link_to image_tag("image", alt: "alt_image", style: "height: 200px;"), "link" , target: :_blank %>
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <h6>More Text</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <%= link_to image_tag("image", alt: "alt_image", style: "height: 200px;"), "link" , target: :_blank %>
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <h6>More Text</h6>
      </div>
    <%# more carousel items %>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```